# How to bind array for DataGridComboBoxColumn WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a DataGrid with Combobox

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Header 2" ItemsSource="{Binding Pet}">
```

Project based on MVVM pattern. When I try to display data on TextColumn, it works

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 1" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
```

But, I don't know, how to bind the data for DataGridComboBoxColumn.

The code of Model:

```
    public string ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ID"); }
    }
    public string[] Pet
    {
        get { return _pet; }
        set { _pet = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Pet"); }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `<DataGridComboBoxColumn>` try using `<DataGridTemplateColumn>` like this

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Pet, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" SelectedItem="{Binding ID}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In this example, I have bound my Combobox's item source as Pet array collection defined in my current ViewModel and the selected item as the ID property of the List<> collection bound to the complete DataGrid.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't work for me. I have a model `public class ListItem` wich contains property `public string[] Pet` and I try to get datas from it. Should I need to change type of property Pet? Also, I bound `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}"...>` before and that's why binding for `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 1" Binding="{Binding ID}" />` works fine.

Comment: Assuming that ListItems is a collection of ListItem class. Then just ignore the RelativeSource part in the binding and simply write `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pet}"/>` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

DataGridComboBoxColumn and DataGridTextColumn won't participate in logical tree. So binding won't work in this. You can overcome this in the below two ways,
1. Define your view model as static resource and StaticResource binding
2. You can use RelativeSource binding which will also work for your case

Refer the below blog for more information about how to do,
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/28/wpf-datagrid-working-with-datagridcomboboxcolumns-part-2.aspx

Comment: I tried to bind as a StaticResource `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Pet}}"` and I received an error `XamlParseException`

Comment: you can refer the below link, http://lfhck.com/question/378365/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem for a day now, and have found this to be a better solution, as it doesn't mess up rendering of the combobox:

```
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ID" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ID}">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Pet}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Pet}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```